# At the vs With the

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

> My heart grieves **with the thought** that he will stay back. 
>  **Vs** 
> My heart
> grieves **at the thought** that he will stay back.

Grammarly corrects the first sentence to the second one. However, I have come across the first structure a lot more than the second. At the thought and With the thought—can these two be used interchangeably? Or do they mean different?

Comment: to me "grieving at the thought (of ?)" sounds much familiar and more natural than "grieving with the thought". I am not a native though. BTW, I would say "grieving at the though of him staying back".

Comment: We grieve **at** things that make us very sad; we grieve **with** people whose sadness we share.

Answer (score 0):

Both sound OK to me. To portray a direct reaction to something, "at" might be better (e.g. physical reactions like "I jumped at the noise", "I laughed at the joke"). To portray the effect of contemplating a topic, "with" might be better. Emotions can often be portrayed either way.